# How to fix pcre2 to \w will match marks?

Tags: c, regex, pcre

I use Pcre2 lib that can be found [here](https://www.pcre.org/).

As you can see [here](https://github.com/svn2github/pcre2/blob/ba0cbc98725a5cfa538da8b49b208a0b1f3e0bb2/src/pcre2_internal.h#L1246) Pcre2 `\w` matches only `L` and `N` categories and underscore and not matches `M` - marks (see [here](https://regex101.com/r/5v8jZi/1)). However .Net Regex matches marks (see [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cw&i=s%CC%8Clug%CC%A7%20slug)).

I want to change the source code of PCRE2 to behave like .Net Regex, only I'm not sure I'm doing right.

What I want to do is find in the code where `PT_WORD` is referenced, like [this](https://github.com/svn2github/pcre2/blob/46d95c641785318f9cd9f0de93b97bef41341806/src/pcre2_match.c#L2407):

```
case PT_WORD:
    if ((PRIV(ucp_gentype)[prop->chartype] == ucp_L ||
         PRIV(ucp_gentype)[prop->chartype] == ucp_N ||
         fc == CHAR_UNDERSCORE) == (Fop == OP_NOTPROP))
```

And add another line like that:

```
case PT_WORD:
    if ((PRIV(ucp_gentype)[prop->chartype] == ucp_L ||
         PRIV(ucp_gentype)[prop->chartype] == ucp_N ||
         PRIV(ucp_gentype)[prop->chartype] == ucp_M || // <-- new line
         fc == CHAR_UNDERSCORE) == (Fop == OP_NOTPROP))
```

Is it right to do so? Are there other things to consider? What else do I need to change elsewhere in the code?

Answer (score 2):

A [.NET `\w` construct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#word-character-w) matches

```
Category    Description
Ll          Letter, Lowercase
Lu          Letter, Uppercase
Lt          Letter, Titlecase
Lo          Letter, Other
Lm          Letter, Modifier
Mn          Mark, Nonspacing
Nd          Number, Decimal Digit
Pc          Punctuation, Connector. This category includes ten characters, the most commonly used of which is the LOWLINE character (_), u+005F.
```

Note the differences: .NET `\w` does not match all numbers, only those from the [`Nd` category](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm), and as for the `M` category, it only matches [`Mn`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/list.htm) subset.

Make sure you match these Unicode categories within your code and `\w` will behave as in .NET regex.

Use

```
case PT_WORD:
    if ((PRIV(ucp_gentype)[prop->chartype] == ucp_Ll ||
         PRIV(ucp_gentype)[prop->chartype] == ucp_Lu ||
         PRIV(ucp_gentype)[prop->chartype] == ucp_Lt ||
         PRIV(ucp_gentype)[prop->chartype] == ucp_Lo ||
         PRIV(ucp_gentype)[prop->chartype] == ucp_Lm ||
         PRIV(ucp_gentype)[prop->chartype] == ucp_Mn ||
         PRIV(ucp_gentype)[prop->chartype] == ucp_Nd ||
         PRIV(ucp_gentype)[prop->chartype] == ucp_Lm ||
         PRIV(ucp_gentype)[prop->chartype] == ucp_Pc) == (Fop == OP_NOTPROP))
      RRETURN(MATCH_NOMATCH);
break;
```

Note you do not need to care about `fc == CHAR_UNDERSCORE` as it is part of `\p{Pc}` and you can't use just `ucp_L` as it also includes `\p{LC}`.